# Beta distribution: find the parameter $\alpha$ of $\mathcal{B}e(\alpha,\frac{1}{3})$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, gamma-function, beta-function

I have this variable with beta distribution : $Y \sim \mathcal{B}e(\alpha,\frac{1}{3})$.

I have to find the value of $\alpha$ such as :
$P(Y \leq 0.416) =0.2 $

Formally for $\alpha \geq 0$ , $\beta \geq 0$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$ the CDF function of $Y$ at 0.416 is:

$P(Y \leq 0.416) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \int_0^{0.416} t^{\alpha-1} (1-t)^{\beta-1} dt=0.2$

I am not sure how to proceed. Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Maple gives the CDF for $\mathcal{B}e(\alpha,\beta)$ as
$$ {\frac {\Gamma \left( \alpha+\beta \right) {y}^{\alpha}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(\alpha,1-\beta;\,1+\alpha;\,y)}}{\Gamma \left( 
\alpha \right) \Gamma \left( \beta \right) \alpha}}
$$
In any case, you need to use numerical methods to solve $F(0.416) = 0.2$.
Maple says $\alpha = 0.8563203833$.

Comment: The question is stated as though an analytical solution is expected...but I agree that numerical methods are the way to proceed here.

Comment: thank you very much for the kind answer. But i don't understand the meaning of this quantity: ${\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(\alpha,1-\beta;\,1+\alpha;\,y)}$. And how did you obtain the value of $\alpha$? Thank you in advance @Robert Israel

Comment: Can i get a solution with the software R?

Comment: ${}_2F_1(a,b; c; z)$ is a [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).  The value of $\alpha$ was obtained using a numerical solver (fsolve in Maple).